# facebook login popup hangs on xd_proxy in chrome and ff

Tags: javascript, facebook

previously using the facebook fb:login-button was working in all browsers except ie .... without changed any code this week it unexpectedly stopped working in all browsers.  I reworked the code to use fb.login and now it works in ie and not in any other broswers (chrome nor ff  safari is untested ).  It pops up and auth goes fine in ff and chrome but window hangs on 
https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3#cb=f1fc2ca85ee4c5a&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.textbooksrus.com%2Ffaae3192c00712&relation=opener&transport=flash&frame=f2fdac213bd74de&access_token=AAAAAGAl9kZCQBAMnOf0lu8XMOqlogMwNUgQZCWZBDEtxjOaGODoaLDV7LaQT21KYBXZCzYwquVJ83TXDPSH0VE6YLTbL5TaVRFq4NbnX2QZDZD&expires_in=5673&signed_request=........

try going to www.textbooksrus.com/customer/login2.aspx

have stripped down script to almost exactly what was in their example of the new oauth 2.0.

```
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                              FB.init({ appId: 'my app id', 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});

  function updateButton(response) {
    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

    if (response.authResponse) {
      //user is already logged in and connected
      var userInfo = document.getElementById('fbMessage');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
         userInfo.innerHTML=response.name;
        button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
      });
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
        var userInfo = document.getElementById('fbMessage');
          userInfo.innerHTML='';
    });
      };
    } else {
      //user is not connected to your app or logged out
      button.innerHTML = 'Login';
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('fbMessage');
           userInfo.innerHTML= response.name;
        });    
          } else {
            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
          }
        }, {scope:'email'});    
      }
    }
  }

  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    
};
```

wasted way too much time on this ... have tried flash fix .... have tried channel url file .. have tried just about everything ... please show me some love